# Using variables in command line

Tags: unix, command-line

I wrote a code and it works great but I need to use variables instead static numbers for scopes 8 and 16

```
cat /etc/passwd | sed '/^#/d' | sed -n 'n;p' | sed 's/:\(.*\) //g' | sed 's/ /,/g' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1./' | sort -r | sed 's/*rav://g' | sed "s/:.*//" | rev | sed -n -e '8,16p' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /, /g' | sed '/:[0-9]*$/ ! s/$/./'
```

I've changed the code to

```
cat /etc/passwd | sed '/^#/d' | sed -n 'n;p' | sed 's/:\(.*\) //g' | sed 's/ /,/g' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1./' | sort -r | sed 's/*rav://g' | sed "s/:.*//" | rev | sed -n -e '$FT_LINE1,$FT_LINE2+p' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /, /g' | sed '/:[0-9]*$/ ! s/$/./'
```

but I got a error

```
sed: 1: "$FT_LINE1,$FT_LINE2p": invalid command code F
```

Comment: Beware of "useless use of cat" and save a process by making the first command: `sed '/^#/d' < /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables enclosed inside single quotes are not expanded by shell and hence your `sed` command sees the argument `$FT_LINE1,$FT_LINE2p` literally.  Use double quotes and you will be fine:

```
sed -n -e "$FT_LINE1,${FT_LINE2}p"
```

---

See also:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: maybe you also can explain the one more thing. when I am using ft1=8 and ft2 = 15 its showed shifted result by 1 to the right, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Surround your variables with curly braces so the shell knows where the variable name ends:

```
sed -n -e "${FT_LINE1},${FT_LINE2}p"
```

EDIT - D'oh I can't believe I missed the single quotes.  They need to be double quotes as others have pointed out so variable substitution will occur.

Comment: Still the same 

cat /etc/passwd | sed '/^#/d' | sed -n 'n;p' | sed 's/:\(.*\) //g' | sed 's/ /,/g' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1./' | sort -r | sed 's/*rav://g' | sed "s/:.*//" | rev | sed -n -e '${FT_LINE1},${FT_LINE2}p' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /, /g' | sed '/:[0-9]*$/ ! s/$/./'

               Error              sed: 1: "${FT_LINE1},${FT_LINE2}p
": invalid command code F